# how do i make the intellij android preview window stay open?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I know there has to be an easy way to do this but haven't found it. I have an android layout open in text + preview window and have my `styles.xml` split below it. Every time I click in the `styles.xml` window the preview window disappears. Any way to keep it open while I'm editing the styles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option is located under the gear icon:

[image: gear]

Answer (score 9):

On Android Studio 3.0 is a bit different, but still easy:

[image: Android Studio 3.0]